# ElasticSearch Stack Monitoring Versus OpenSearch Index stats

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-cloudwatch, opensearch

Is there a similar way in OpenSearch to get the Index Stats that is available in ElasticSearch Stack Monitoring for example the Advanced Index stats like cache usage etc.

Thanks.